# instrumentation tests stops working after rebuild: No tests found

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-testing

I'm trying to get the androidTest (instrumentation tests) working for the [openScale](https://github.com/oliexdev/openScale) Android app using the following build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.health.openscale"
        testApplicationId "com.health.openscale.test"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 22 // don't set target sdk > 22 otherwise bluetooth le discovery need permission to ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
        versionCode 22
        versionName "1.7 (beta)"

        javaCompileOptions {
            annotationProcessorOptions { arguments = ["room.schemaLocation":"$projectDir/schemas".toString()] }
        }

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    sourceSets {
        androidTest.assets.srcDirs += files("$projectDir/schemas".toString())
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

ext {
    supportLibVersion = '27.0.2'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "com.android.support:design:${supportLibVersion}"
    implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:${supportLibVersion}"
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${supportLibVersion}"

    // HelloCharts
    implementation 'com.github.lecho:hellocharts-library:1.5.8@aar'

    // Simple CSV
    implementation 'com.j256.simplecsv:simplecsv:2.2'

    // CustomActivityOnCrash
    implementation 'cat.ereza:customactivityoncrash:2.2.0'

    // Room
    implementation 'android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.0.0'
    annotationProcessor 'android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.0.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'android.arch.persistence.room:testing:1.0.0'

    // Local unit tests
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

    // Instrumented unit tests
    androidTestImplementation "com.android.support:support-annotations:${supportLibVersion}"
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:rules:1.0.1'
}

tasks.withType(Test) {
    testLogging {
        exceptionFormat "full"
        events "started", "skipped", "passed", "failed"
        showStandardStreams true
    }
}
```

There's a single test file under android_app/app/src/androidTest/java/com.health.openscale/DatabaseTest.java

I'm using the command `./gradlew --no-daemon --no-build-cache -i connectedDebugAndroidTest` to build and run the tests and it works fine the first time: both tests in the file are executed and pass.

But now, if I change the test file (small change to trigger a rebuild) and run the above command again I get the following output:

```
...
Putting task artifact state for task ':app:compileDebugAndroidTestJavaWithJavac' into context took 0.0 secs.
file or directory '/<path>/android_app/app/src/androidTestDebug/java', not found
Executing task ':app:compileDebugAndroidTestJavaWithJavac' (up-to-date check took 0.007 secs) due to:
  Input property 'source' file /<path>/android_app/app/src/androidTest/java/com.health.openscale/DatabaseTest.java has changed.
Compiling with source level 1.7 and target level 1.7.
...
Putting task artifact state for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebugAndroidTest' into context took 0.0 secs.
Executing task ':app:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebugAndroidTest' (up-to-date check took 0.024 secs) due to:
  Input property '$3' file /<path>/android_app/app/build/intermediates/classes/androidTest/debug/com/health/openscale/DatabaseTest.class has been removed.
Transform inputs calculations based on following changes
/<path>/android_app/app/build/intermediates/classes/androidTest/debug/com/health/openscale/DatabaseTest.class:REMOVED
...
Starting 0 tests on Nexus_5X_API_26(AVD) - 8.0.0
[XmlResultReporter]: XML test result file generated at /<path>/android_app/app/build/outputs/androidTest-results/connected/TEST-Nexus_5X_API_26(AVD) - 8.0.0-app-.xml. Total tests 0, 

com.android.builder.testing.ConnectedDevice > No tests found.[Nexus_5X_API_26(AVD) - 8.0.0] FAILED
No tests found. This usually means that your test classes are not in the form that your test runner expects (e.g. don't inherit from TestCase or lack @Test annotations).
[XmlResultReporter]: XML test result file generated at /<path>/android_app/app/build/outputs/androidTest-results/connected/TEST-Nexus_5X_API_26(AVD) - 8.0.0-app-.xml. Total tests 1, failure 1, 
...
```

Does anyone know why the rebuild doesn't work? Why is the class removed from the build?

I have verified with the APK analyzer in Android studio that the DatabaseTest class is indeed missing from the APK after the rebuild.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that moving the test case from `.../com.health.openscale/DatabaseTest.java` to `.../com/health/openscale/DatabaseTest.java` fixed the problem.